# MLE issues in R

Tags: r, mle

I am new to R and taught myself what I know of R based on the other languages i know. I am in a student research position currently and must use R to find the maximum likelihood estimate of the given likelihood function:

[image]

Where g, m_i, x_ij, n_ij, and mu_i are known. I have to maximize theta_i, but i am not sure how since i am mostly self taught. I do know that i should have six estimated values of theta, however. I have tried doing research online about using mle but I am not far into Statistics to understand what the websites are talking about. Any help in figuring out what i am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. I am unsure how to attach excel files, so i apologize not being able to include data tables.

In trying to teach myself this and work with the professor we receive this error:

> Error in do.call("minuslogl", l) : could not find function "minuslogl"

Below is the code i have done up until this point:

---

```
library(stats4)
#####################################################################
#Liklihood Model ####CHECK
###################################################################
BB <- function(LITTERS, responses, fetuses, mu, theta) {
  total <- 0

  #1
  for (i in 1:6) {
    firstSum <- 0

    #2
    for (j in 1:LITTERS) {
      secondSum <- 0

      #log(mu[i] + kTheta[i])
      insideFirst <- 0
      for (k in 0:(responses[i,j] - 1)) 
      {
        insideFirst <- insideFirst + log10(mu[i] + k * theta[i])

      }

      #log(1-mu[i] + kTheta[i])
      insideSecond <- 0
      for (k in 0:(fetuses[i,j] - responses[i,j] - 1)) 
      {
        insideSecond <- insideSecond + log10(1 - mu[i] + k * theta[i])
      }

      #log(1 + kTheta[i])
      insideThird <- 0
      for (k in 0:(fetuses[i,j] - 1)) 
      {
        insideThird <- insideThird + log10(1 + k * theta[i])
      }

      secondSum <- insideFirst + insideSecond - insideThird
      firstSum <- firstSum + secondSum
    }
    total <- total + firstSum
  }
  return (total)
}
###################################################################
#Number of litters
LITTERS.M <- 25

doses <- c(0, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90)

  #Retrieves the litter sizes (fetuses)
  litterSize.dose0 <- get.Litter.Sizes(dose0, LITTERS.M)
  litterSize.dose30 <- get.Litter.Sizes(dose30, LITTERS.M)
  litterSize.dose45 <- get.Litter.Sizes(dose45, LITTERS.M)
  litterSize.dose60 <- get.Litter.Sizes(dose60, LITTERS.M)
  litterSize.dose75 <- get.Litter.Sizes(dose75, LITTERS.M)
  litterSize.dose90 <- get.Litter.Sizes(dose90, LITTERS.M)
  litterSize <- c(litterSize.dose0, litterSize.dose30, litterSize.dose45, litterSize.dose60, litterSize.dose75, litterSize.dose90)
  litterSizes <- matrix(litterSize, nrow = 6, ncol = LITTERS.M)

  #Start of Linear Regression for AB By first estimating AB
  estimate.dose0 <- get.estimate.AB(dose0)
  estimate.dose30 <- get.estimate.AB(dose30)
  estimate.dose45 <- get.estimate.AB(dose45)
  estimate.dose60 <- get.estimate.AB(dose60)
  estimate.dose75 <- get.estimate.AB(dose75)
  estimate.dose90 <- get.estimate.AB(dose90)

  rProbR <- c(estimate.dose0, estimate.dose30, estimate.dose45, estimate.dose60,
             estimate.dose75, estimate.dose90)

  ab <- c(get.Log.Estimate(estimate.dose0), get.Log.Estimate(estimate.dose30), get.Log.Estimate(estimate.dose45),
         get.Log.Estimate(estimate.dose60), get.Log.Estimate(estimate.dose75), get.Log.Estimate(estimate.dose90))

  #Fit to Linear Regression
  toFit <- data.frame(rProbR, ab)

  linearRegression <- lm(ab ~ rProbR, data=toFit)
  #Get Coefficients of linear regression of AB
  AApproximation = linearRegression$coefficients[1]
  BApproximation = linearRegression$coefficients[2]


  #Get probability response for each dose group (P(D[i]))
  probabilityResponse.dose0 <- get.Probability.Response.Logistic(AApproximation + BApproximation * 0)
  probabilityResponse.dose30 <- get.Probability.Response.Logistic(AApproximation + BApproximation * 30)
  probabilityResponse.dose45 <- get.Probability.Response.Logistic(AApproximation + BApproximation * 45)
  probabilityResponse.dose60 <- get.Probability.Response.Logistic(AApproximation + BApproximation * 60)
  probabilityResponse.dose75 <- get.Probability.Response.Logistic(AApproximation + BApproximation* 75)
  probabilityResponse.dose90 <- get.Probability.Response.Logistic(AApproximation + BApproximation * 90)
  probabilityResponses <- c(probabilityResponse.dose0, probabilityResponse.dose30, probabilityResponse.dose45, probabilityResponse.dose60, probabilityResponse.dose75, probabilityResponse.dose90)

  #Generate number of responses for each litter (Responses)
  litterResponses.dose0 <- rbinom(LITTERS.M, litterSize.dose0, probabilityResponse.dose0)
  litterResponses.dose30 <- rbinom(LITTERS.M, litterSize.dose30, probabilityResponse.dose30)
  litterResponses.dose45 <- rbinom(LITTERS.M, litterSize.dose45, probabilityResponse.dose45)
  litterResponses.dose60 <- rbinom(LITTERS.M, litterSize.dose60, probabilityResponse.dose60)
  litterResponses.dose75 <- rbinom(LITTERS.M, litterSize.dose75, probabilityResponse.dose75)
  litterResponses.dose90 <- rbinom(LITTERS.M, litterSize.dose90, probabilityResponse.dose90)
  litterResponse <- c(litterResponses.dose0, litterResponses.dose30, litterResponses.dose45, litterResponses.dose60, litterResponses.dose75, litterResponses.dose90)
  litterResponses <- matrix(litterResponse, 6, LITTERS.M)


  backgroundResponseProb <- get.Probability.Response.Logistic(AApproximation + BApproximation * 0)
  backgroundResponseProb <- backgroundResponseProb + .001


  mle(BB(LITTERS.M, litterResponses, litterSizes, probabilityResponse, theta=0))
```

Comment: The code is not completed yet, so there may be unused variables such as BMDList[50]. There is obviously no index since i have commented out the loop. It is a simulation program.

Comment: you're probably have to focus/narrow down this question and give a reproducible example in order to get help -- it's unlikely that people will want to slog through this much code ...

Comment: The only issue I'm having is with the mle function. Should I only display that section of code? Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: generally, the advice is to take some time and effort to try to boil the problem down to something shorter.  This can be difficult, but (1) you owe it to the people taking the effort to try to help you and (2) in the process of boiling the problem down you often clarify for yourself what the problem is, and sometimes solve it ...

Answer (score 5):

I haven't gone through the entire code (you should try to provide *minimal* reproducible examples), but the error you're getting is caused by the fact that you're not using the `mle` function correctly.

The first argument to the `mle` function should be another function that takes candidate parameters as arguments, and returns the negative log-likelihood of the data as a function of these parameters. The second argument to the `mle` function is a named list of starting parameters. Look at `?mle` for more details.

Here's a minimal example for fitting normally distributed data:

```
library(stats4)
y <- rnorm(100, 5, 3)  ## Example data
mllNorm <- function(mean, log.sd) {-sum(dnorm(y, mean, exp(log.sd), log=TRUE))}  ## Minus Gaussian log-likelihood
mle.fit <- mle(mllNorm, start=list(mean=1, log.sd=1))  ## MLE
print(mle.fit)
```

As a more general tip, I highly recommend the `maxLik` package for MLE. It offers a more flexible interface, prettier output, and more optimization options.