# More MLE troubles

Tags: r, mle

I am in a student research position and am new to R. I have asked a question similar (posted here:[MLE Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756745/mle-issues-in-r)). I have resolved the initial problem but i have encountered more problems with this function.

I am still using this function for trying to estimate theta[i],[image]
where each of the other variables is currently known.

Below is my code:

```
  maxParam <- function(theta) {
    logl <- sum(for (i in 1:length(doses)) {
      sum(
        for (j in 1:LITTERS.M) {
          sum(
            for (k in 0:(litterResponses[i,j]-1)) {
              sum(log10(probabilityResponses[i] + k * theta[i]))
            }
            +
            for (k in 0:(litterSizes[i,j]-litterResponses[i,j]-1)) {
              sum(log10(1 - probabilityResponses[i] + k * theta[i]))
            }
            -
            for (k in 0:(litterSizes[i,j] - 1)) {
              sum(log10(1 + k * theta[i]))
            }
          )
        }
      )
    })

    return (-logl)
  }

  mle.fit <- mle(maxParam, start=list(theta=c(1,1,1,1,1,1)))
  print(mle.fit)
```

The error i am being thrown is:

> Error: argument "theta" is missing, with no default

I apologize if the error is silly, I have little knowledge of R.

**Notes:**
I am using a vector of (1,1,1,1,1,1) as a test for theta. It is not actual data. Doses is a vector of 6 that corresponds to dose levels of a serum. Litter Responses is a matrix that describes the responses to the serum per dose per litter. LitterSizes is a matrix that describes the size of a litter per dose per litter. LITTERS.M is the initial number of litters that came in contact with serum. ProbabilityResponses is a vector that describes the probability that a given mouse will be affected by the serum.

Comment: Which package does `mle` function come from? Take a look at its help file.

Comment: It comes in stats4. I know the function mle needs is a log likelihood function. I believe the error to be in my function I just do not know what I am doing wrong in it.

Comment: I cannot get my function to work in mle. I know what I have to do for the mle function though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `mle` does not accept a vector of initial starting values. Each parameter to be found by optimisation needs to be passed as a scalar. It is sufficient to change the declaration of your function to:

```
maxParam <- function(theta_1 = 1, theta_2 = 1, etc) {
    theta <- unlist(as.list(environment()))

    ... # rest of function follows
  }
```

where `etc` means replace this with `theta_3 = 1`, `theta_4 = 1` as necessary. The function `mle` can then be called with:

```
mle.fit <- mle(maxParam)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a while back. `mle` does not accept vector parameters, where as `mle2` does. [Have look at this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614235/multinomial-mle-error-in-r)